# Pyenv disabling global python libs

Tags: pyenv

Is there an option like '--no-site-packages' to use with pyenv?

when i write :

```
pyvenv-3.5 kesitler_arsivi_env
```

When i activate my env and do pip freeze the global python libraries are listed. I do not need them.